# A string of quarterly dates between a start and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I've got a recursive cte working to generate a list of dates between @startDate and @endDate, incrementing by quarters.

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

set @startDate= '01-jan-2014'
set @endDate= '01-jul-2017'

;With cte
As
( Select @startDate date1
Union All
Select DateAdd(Month,3,date1)   From cte where date1 < @endDate 
) select cast(cast( Year(date1)*10000 + MONTH(date1)*100 + 1 as 
varchar(255)) as date) quarterlyDates From cte
```

This yields:

```
quarterlyDates
--------------
2014-01-01
2014-04-01
2014-07-01
2014-10-01 ...
```

I'd like to concatenate the output of the cte into a single string as follows:

```
"'01-jan-2014', '01-apr-2014, '01-jul-2014'..."
```

etc. I'm baffled by this last step - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's consuming this output? Comma-Separated data *isn't* a natural way of representing multiple values inside SQL Server (unlike, say, rows within tables or XML). If what's consuming this data also doesn't naturally represent data as comma-separated, perhaps we can avoid unnecessary conversions?

Comment: It's going to go some dynamic sql as a string, you're possibly right that this isn't what it needs to go as, but SQL isn't my natural home so I'm building slowly...

Comment: Either the dynamic SQL can be avoided or you could populate a temp table with this data - temp tables from an outer scope are accessible inside dynamic SQL and that would keep the data more naturally represented.

Comment: OK - thanks. I've marked the other reponse as accepted, but I'll check out the temp table scope as well - that's useful.

Comment: This doesn't really go towards your concatenation question, but I would once again recommend my favorite answer of using a Date Dimension / Calendar Table to help pre-calculate the dates you need. Every database should have one. And it both makes your queries faster and makes your life a whole bunch easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to... but just wrap that bottom cte and use stuff.

```
declare @table table(quarterlyDates date)
insert into @table
values
('2014-01-01'),
('2014-04-01'),
('2014-07-01'),
('2014-10-01')

SELECT stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + cast(quarterlyDates as varchar(max))
    FROM @table
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
```

And in your code... though the second CTE isn't necessary I leave it for clarity.

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

set @startDate= '01-jan-2014'
set @endDate= '01-jul-2017'

;With cte
As
( Select @startDate date1
Union All
Select DateAdd(Month,3,date1)   From cte where date1 < @endDate 
), 

cte2 as(
select cast(cast( Year(date1)*10000 + MONTH(date1)*100 + 1 as 
varchar(255)) as date) quarterlyDates From cte)

SELECT stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + cast(quarterlyDates as varchar(max))
    FROM cte2
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `FOR XML Path` with `type` directive to avoid encoding of illegal characters in result

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT @startDate date1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(month, 3, date1) 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  date1 < @endDate) 
SELECT Stuff((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), date1, 106) quarterlyDates 
              FROM   cte 
              FOR xml path, type).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
```

**Note :** I have altered the unwanted manipulating in the final `select`. Use style `106` in `Convert` function to get the required output format

Answer (score 1):

Late answer and just for fun.

**Example**

```
declare @startDate datetime = '01-jan-2014'
declare @endDate datetime   = '01-jul-2017'

;With cte
As
( Select date1 = @startDate
        ,dates = ''''+convert(varchar(max),convert(varchar(11),@startDate,113))+''''
  Union All
  Select DateAdd(Month,3,date1)   
        ,cte.dates+','''+convert(varchar(11),DateAdd(Month,3,date1)   ,106)+''''
   From cte where date1 < @endDate 
) 
Select Top 1 with ties 
       Dates=lower(replace(Dates,' ','-') )
 From cte
 Order By Date1 Desc
```

**Returns**

```
'01-jan-2014','01-apr-2014','01-jul-2014','01-oct-2014','01-jan-2015','01-apr-2015','01-jul-2015','01-oct-2015','01-jan-2016','01-apr-2016','01-jul-2016','01-oct-2016','01-jan-2017','01-apr-2017','01-jul-2017'
```